# Dataframe column according max value of many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for the best way of obtain the dataframe column "Best player" that means the usarname of the player with the minimum time.

I have a way to obtain the column but its no optimized because the numbre of player ca reach up to 6.

This is the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player one':["Juul","RGB10","Holi2","Combo"]\
           ,'Time play1':[13,21,15,4]\
           ,'Player two':["Jar21","helen3","Dimi","kanh"]\
           ,'Time play2':[5,7,19,4]\
           ,'Player three':["josi","Mae","Dylen","Joe18"]\
           ,'Time play3':[4,12,8,66,]
          })
```

And this is the way that I get the column "Best player":

```
df["Best player"]=np.where((df[['Time play1', 'Time play2','Time play3']].min(axis=1))==df["Time play1"]\
,df["Player one"]\
,np.where( (df[['Time play1', 'Time play2','Time play3']].min(axis=1))==df["Time play2"]\
          ,df["Player two"]\
          ,df["Player three"]\
         )\
)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n23kj.jpg

Is there an easier way to get the column?